# when trying to render cshtml files I always get an error saying can't find theme file but theme should be installed

Tags: c#, .net, abp

I was trying to complete my colleagues code because he is on vacation with implementing a simple local login system, we already have saml. This login page will be rendered on the server side and not the front-end which is react. For the styling of this page we use an abp theme (the basic one) I followed the documentation to install the theme but I still always get the same error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: The layout view '~/Themes/Basic/Layouts/Application.cshtml' could not be located. The following locations were searched:
~/Themes/Basic/Layouts/Application.cshtml
```

I installed the package.json file with yarn and added the correct nuget package.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: on top of you cshtml file, is there a Theme="~/Themes/Basic/Layouts/Application.cshtml" or somthing like that?

Comment: @PouyaHashemi there is somethin like that. There is:
`
@{
    Layout = ThemeManager.CurrentTheme.GetApplicationLayout();
}
`